# will Usage of BehaviorSubjects frequently, impact on Application performance?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using Angular7.x in our application.
Using number of BehaviourSubjects are keep on increasing. 
will it effect Application performance?
If so please provide any other alternative for BehaviourSubjects.

Comment: you'll just have to check for yourself if your happy with your application performance or not. if you are not happy with the performance, then you'll have to profile. have you hit a bottleneck with behaviorsubjects?

Comment: I am new to Angular so i am asking...

Answer (score 0):

if you are not unsubscribe the BehaviourSubjects there are chances of memory leak so you can also use **@Output**

here is the example

```
**shared-service**
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
export class SharedService {
  @Output() sendData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
}

**component-one**
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
export class ComponentOneComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.emitData();
 }
 emitData() {
 // this component is emit the data
 this.sharedService.sendData.emit('message from component one');
 }
}

**component-two**
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
export class ComponentTwoComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(public sharedService: SharedService) {
 }
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.sendData.subscribe(data=> {
      console.log(data); // here you can get the data from component one
    });
  }
}
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: actually eventemitter extends subject, so it hardly makes any measurable difference. there's nothing wrong with behaviorsubject.